How to install/compile `ltrace` on raspberry pi OS bookworm
I need to trace shared library calls for a program on a raspberry pi 5 running raspberry pi OS bookworm.
According to some forum posts ltrace used to exist in the raspberry pi package repositories, but I can't install it anymore.
Running apt search ltrace does not list the desired package.
If I run the same on my laptop it shows up and I can install it.
I'm not 100% sure this question even belongs here, but I don't know where else to start.
Does anyone know where I can find the source code and compile it myself on the raspberry pi 5?
Any hint would be appreciated

The following information may not be CURRENT (I don't know if it is or not), but this maybe useful Package: ltrace (0.7.3-6.1). As noted here ltrace and latrace both broken on Buster: "Debian completely removed ltrace / latrace for ARMHF"

You can download the source from gitlab source or directly from the ltrace website and build it
